# angular2 error no provider for ComponentLoaderFactory on upgrading bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have upgraded bootstrap version `ng2-bootstrap` from `1.1.16` to `1.1.17` and so upgraded angular versions from `2.2.4` to `2.4.1.0`.
After that getting **No Provider for componentLoaderFactory for a component** which has bootstrap. The component is in a different module and that module is included in the app module. What will be the issue?

Comment: Show the module code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to add forRoot where i imported the components.

Comment: can you please share the code snippet?